# Having already installed build-tools but fail to find build tools revision 24.0.1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, build-tools

Here i got a problem, I have already installed build tool in revision 24.0.1, here is the screen snapshot from my terminal:

[image: build tool on my computer]

And in fact I think I wrote it well in the build.gradle file`buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"`, but while sync the project it still appear such error:

> fail to find build tool revision 24.0.1 install such build tools

Another question is about the file place order in android studio. Below is the imported project hierarchy and the manifest file is under the main folder and i can not find any usage file under android perspective.

[image: import project hierachy]

Such a project hierarchy I have never seen, maybe there is somebody who could demonstrate such answer to me. Thank you.

**Update:** Here is the build.gradle file picture

[image: build.gralde file picture]

Comment: please show how does your `build.gradle` looks like. Also, I suppose this question can be divided into two separate questions

Comment: ok,i have  update the build.gradle file above

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it in the wrong way. There are two types of `build.gradle` files. The first one is for your `project` and the second type for `module` which can be more than one. In your case you are mixing both.

The project's `build.gradle` should like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and the module `build.gradle` should look something like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.something"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1'
}
```

Comment: your description is right and i think there should be something wrong on the project hierarchy.why the build.gradle(module) under the app folder and it's appeared in the project perspective.at the same time i don't think the build.gradle file content is wrong,compare your file and mine. there are no differences.

Comment: Open the standalone sdk manager and check whether you have installed all the required stuffs just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your second question, the hierarchy you see is called `Project` view.

[image]

> By default, Android Studio displays your project files in the **Android view**. This view does not reflect the actual file hierarchy on disk, but **is organized by modules and file types** to simplify navigation between key source files of your project, hiding certain files or directories that are not commonly used.
>   (...) To **see the actual file structure** of the project including all files hidden from the Android view, **select Project from the dropdown at the top of the Project window.**

Source: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/index.html